# Outlook EWS > GetUserConfiguration from Mail Add-In

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi

I am attempting to get a user configuration setting, using [GetUserConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getuserconfiguration-operation), from an Add-In. I receive the response...

> The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook/add-ins/web-services), this method is not supported for Add-Ins.

Is there any other way to access these settings, either with EWS, or the REST api ?

I can see that my settings are stored in the message store, as an associated message, under "Root - Mailbox\IPM_SUBTREE". Can I access associated messages directly, via EWS or REST ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EWS to get the Folder Associated Items so you should be able to read it okay, however if you want to update the item you won't be able to use the UpdateItem (it will throw an error "Office extension is not allowed to update this type of item")

Comment: Thanks Glen, but I still get the same error, when trying to access GetFolder or FindItem  - which is at odds with the article that i mentioned above..

One thing that I didn't mention (don't think it should matter), is that I am using a callbackToken (from javascript - getCallbackTokenAsync) - but passing it to my web server and making the request from there.

There's a header in the response: x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;reason="The web method in the request is not allowed with this token.";error_category="invalid_grant"

Comment: You can't use the callback token for this that is a s limited use token you need to use makeEwsRequestAsync